# Disable Intel Graphics card

Tags: windows-7, switchable-graphics

I have an HP ProBook with two cards, an Intel and an AMD Radeon HD 7850M. I want to switch to the AMD, because it is better that way. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you do it in AMD Catalyst? What model is the AMD card?

Comment: So have you tried doing it the Catalyst Center?

Comment: I want to use it for a game. I have tried enabling it for the game with Catalyst, but the game recognizes the Intel only.

Comment: What game? If you have set the game to run with AMD then I don't see how the game can only recognises Intel.

Comment: WHy do you think I am asking here? I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to tell *all programs* on your laptop to use the AMD graphics card.  This isn't how it works.  Instead, you "switch" to the AMD graphics card *on a per-application* basis.

To use the AMD graphics card with a certain application, right-click the application icon and choose the appropriate option on the context menu to use your AMD graphics card for that application.  The program will run and its graphics processing needs will be handled by the AMD graphics card, but other programs will continue using Intel adapter.